# Using an existing neo4j graph database for quering instead of creating a new database (same) everytime

Tags: neo4j

I have created a graph database from a pile of 30k xml files. I want to reuse this graph database for querying it. Currently, I create the graph database every time I have to query something from it. Since the data set is huge, the database creation takes approx. 40 min. I am not aware of the way of reusing the existing database instead of creating it every time. I would appreciate your help if you could tell me how to do this.
(Java language, IDE-> IntelliJ, Redhat Linux).

Comment: How this ?! I don't understand what exactly make you create the graph every time you run a query !!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Neo4j is a database (forget, for a moment, that it's a *graph* database). Like any other database, it's designed to persist over time, rather than being created for a one-time use and then destroyed. What particular use case leads you to creating the database each time you want to run a query, vs just connecting to your database server and querying it as often as you like?

Answer (score 0):

I am new in this, but I saw there is a Delete database method in several code. Perhaps this is your case.  Try commenting out the delete database method o delete ir, and only use start and shutdown.

I am trying to know how use a database without start and shutdown each time Java code run, perhaps with api REST.  I have no answer yet, but I am still searching.

Answer (score 0):

First you should make sure your import logic and your query logic are not on the same code, and you can call on without the other.

The database you create is stored in a directory.

- If you're on server mode, it is specified on the config file : `neo4j-server.properties` (look for `org.neo4j.server.database.location`).
- If you're on embedded mode, you declare the path of the database to the graph factory:

  graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( PATH/TO/NEO.DB );

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by reusing? If you want to use the database from more than one client at the same time, use Neo4j Server and REST, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/rest-api.html and point the server to your database directory in conf/neo4j-server.properties.

Also, you can point a new instance of Neo4j to the same database directory and that way open the database you created (exclusively), see https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/master/community/embedded-examples/src/main/java/org/neo4j/examples/EmbeddedNeo4j.java#L35

Is that covering your usecase?

/peter

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, which resulted from sloppy copy pasting of the [code snippets](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/2.2.4/community/embedded-examples/src/main/java/org/neo4j/examples/EmbeddedNeo4j.java) from the [Neo4j documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-hello-world.html). Each time I ran the code, all previously created nodes were deleted.

Apart from deleting the `removeData`-method (as mentioned by Jose) you should also remove the following line in the `createDb()`-method to prevent this:

```
FileUtils.deleteRecursively( new File( DB_PATH ) );
```

Maybe this still helps anyone, even though the topic is old.